# Get Acl from powershell and GetAccessControl from c# throw errorcode 50 for a folder created in NFS drive

Tags: c#, powershell, nfs

I am able to create folder in a NFS drive manually.  Say E drive and folder name is ***checkwrite***
but when I run Get-Acl E:\checkwrite , I get the following exception:

```
Get-Acl : Method failed with unexpected error code 50.
At line:1 char:1
+ Get-Acl
+ ~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Get-Acl], InvalidOperationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : System.InvalidOperationException,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.GetAclCommand
```

When I run GetAccessControl over the folder from c# code ,  I get

Exception Message:  Method failed with unexpected error code 50.

Stack trace:

```
at System.Security.AccessControl.NativeObjectSecurity.CreateInternal(ResourceType resourceType, Boolean isContainer, String name, SafeHandle handle, AccessControlSections includeSections, Boolean createByName, ExceptionFromErrorCode exceptionFromErrorCode, Object exceptionContext)
  at System.Security.AccessControl.FileSystemSecurity..ctor(Boolean isContainer, String name, AccessControlSections includeSections, Boolean isDirectory)
  at System.Security.AccessControl.DirectorySecurity..ctor(String name, AccessControlSections includeSections)
  at System.IO.DirectoryInfo.GetAccessControl()
```

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/debug/system-error-codes--0-499-?redirectedfrom=MSDN
from here, it looks like request is not supported.
but If i run the same command for local drive like folders in C, it works.

Any ideas here? How to debug this?

Comment: I'd guess that `>NUL icacls.exe E:\*` ends up with `E:\checkwrite: Access is denied.`?

Comment: E:\> icacls checkwrite resulted in error saying that checkwrite is incorrect function

Comment: What is the underlying filesystem of the share? As far as I know Get-Acl only works for NTFS filesystems